# Laravel:Error when Implementing JWT authentication

Tags: laravel, api, jwt, postman

I am experiencing an error when trying to post the API through Postman to authenticate users in the site.

login function:

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {

     $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

     if ($token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
     }
     return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);

  }
```

the guard function

```
  public function guard()
  {
   return Auth::guard();
  }
```

The error shown on postman

```
"message": "Call to undefined method Tymon\\JWTAuth\\Contracts\\Providers\\Auth::guard()",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\JWTAuth::attempt` function in order to get token if the user inserts valid email and password like:

```
....

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

....

try {
            $token = \JWTAuth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'));
            return $this->respondWithToken($token);
        } catch (JWTException $exception) {

                return response()->json([
                    'status' => false,
                    'data' => null,
                    'message' => 'Could not create token'
                ]);

        }
```

**EDIT 1**

The above answer you submitted is correct.

try replacing `Auth::guard()` to `Auth::guard('api')`

```
public function guard()
  {
   return Auth::guard('api');
  }
```

For more information [there is a similar issue in GitHub for reference](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1484)

Comment: I tried it now, but it displays an error: Method Illuminate\\Auth\\SessionGuard::factory does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use a construct method like

```
public function __construct(){
    auth()->setDefaultDriver('api'); 
}
```

and your login function like

```
public function login(){
$credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

if(!$token = auth()->attempt($credentials)){
  return response()->json(['error' => 'Incorrect email/password'], 401);
}
return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}
```

And comment out your guard function

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem continuously. But the solution was when I used `bcrypt()` on the password.

```
bcrypt($password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dependency injection and inject the Auth interface into your class. Code example below.

From the Tymon package import the Auth interface.

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\Providers\Auth;
```

In your constructor

```
public function __construct(Auth $auth)
{
    $this->_authentication = $auth;
}
```

Then use the "byCredentials" method

```
if (! $token = $this->_authentication->byCredentials($credentials))
{
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
}
```